# Negative running coupling constant in QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics

Considering the one-loop running coupling constant in QCD:
$$\alpha_s(\mu) = \frac{a_s(\mu_0)}{1 + \frac{33-2f}{6 \pi}ln\left( \frac{\mu}{\mu_0}\right)}$$
where f is the number of quarks flavours with mass $2m_q \leq \mu $
I'd like to compute the formula for the energy $\mu=2m_c = 2.8$ GeV where $m_c$ is the upper limit on the charm quark mass.

Knowing that $\alpha_s(m_z)=0.12$ where $m_z = 91$GeV I considered $\mu_0 = m_z$ but I this way I obtain $\alpha_s(\mu)= - 0.057$ where I put f = 4 to include up-down-strange and charm quarks.

> This definitely makes no sense. Where am I wrong? Do I need to change $\mu_0$ and $\alpha(\mu_0)$?

In this last case what values do I need to consider?

Comment: Which μ does your expression blow up for?

Comment: Thank you so much I did a silly mistake, in fact with that formula the expression blows up for a wrong value.